# process.waitFor() does not end

Tags: java, perl

I have a JAVA code where I am executing a perl script. 
Some scripts donot return a response code but require passwords for execution. My code does not return in those cases and process.waitFor() endlessly waits. 
    Is there a way I can handle this?

```
Process process = pb.start();
            int returnCode = process.waitFor();
            System.out.print("return code>>"+ returnCode );
```

My code has the objective to run the command and show the response code.

Comment: Do you have access to the perl scripts? If you can, perhaps it's worth changing them to not require user input.

Comment: Thanks Sunil..But I can't change the scripts not to have passwords or other user inputs. It's a part of existing product.

Answer (score 1):

I see two choices here:

- you can manage correctly stdin of the process by getting its `OutputStream` through `Proecess::getOutputStream` so that you can correctly send input and let the process finish
- you can destroy the process (see [`Process::destroy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#destroy--) or [`Process::destroyForcibly`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#destroyForcibly--)) but this implies that you must choose a maximum amount of time to wait before doing so (and could create problems since you are actually trying to kill a process maybe in the middle of some operation)

Comment: I can not destroy the process as different command take different time to execute. Can you suggest something where I can enter a password when the subprocess needs it.